# Multi Tenant application using MapRoute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multi-tenant

I have found a solution for implement multi-tenant in my asp.net mvc project and 
I want know if it's correct or exist a better way.

I want organize more customers using the same application handling the web request, for example:

```
http://mysite/<customer>/home/index        //home is controller and index the action
```

For this reason i changed the default maproute:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{customername}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

and I implemented a custom ActionFilterAttribute:

```
public class CheckCustomerNameFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting( ActionExecutingContext filterContext )
    {
        var customerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["customername"];

        var customerRepository = new CustomerRepository();

        var customer = customerRepository.GetByName( customerName );

        if( customer == null )
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult { ViewName = "Error" };
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting( filterContext );
    }
}
```

and using it:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [CheckCustomerNameFilterAttribute]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var customerName = RouteData.Values["customername"];

        // show home page of customer with name == customerName

        return View();
    }
}
```

With this solution i can switch customer using customer name and correctly accept requests like this:

```
http://mysite/customer1
http://mysite/customer2/product/detail/2
...................................
```

This solution works well but I don't know if the best approach.
Does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You can model bind the customer name, and not have to pull it from route values:

```
public ActionResult Index(string customerName)
{
}
```